# set of limit points of dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

1. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and both $A$ and $A^{c}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Can we find $x \in A$ such that $x$ is NOT a limit point of $A$?
2. Let $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $B$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is the closure of complement of $B$ supposed to be contained in the boundary of B? In other words, is it always $cl(B^{c}) \subseteq bd(B)$?

Please give me hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $a\in A$, then for every open set $U\ni a$ we have that $U\setminus\{a\}$ is open and nonempty. So there's a point $a'\in U\cap A$, $a'\ne a$, because $A$ is dense. This proves that $a$ is a limit point of $A$.
2. $\text{cl}(B)=\mathbb R^n$, because $B$ is dense, so $\text{bd}(B)=\text{cl}(B)\cap\text{cl}(B^c)=\mathbb R^n\cap\text{cl}(B^c)=\text{cl}(B^c)$.

Note that you didn't need the density of $A^c$ in your first exercise. Is your formulation correct?

Comment: Some arguments on 1 are bit curious. Since $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any open neighborhood of $a \in A$, although we can find an element inside the neighborhood, but that element need not be an element of $A$.

Comment: @fiverules See that $U\setminus\{a\}$ is nonempty open. So it intersects $A$ by the definition of density of $A$. So $(U\setminus\{a\})\cap A$ is not empty, that's where the point $a'$ came from. I thought this was obvious.

Comment: Oh.. I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Anwer on 1):

Assume that $x\in A$ is not a limitpoint of $A$. Then an open set
$U$ exists with $U\cap A=\left\{ x\right\} $. Then $U\neq\emptyset$.
Also $U\ne\left\{ x\right\} $ since $\left\{ x\right\} $ is not
an open set. Then some $y\in U$ exists with $x\ne y$. Let $V$
be an open set with $y\in V$ and $x\notin V$. Then $W:=U\cap V$
is a non-empty (it contains $y$) open set with $W\cap A=\emptyset$. This contradicts
that $A$ is dense and we conclude that it cannot be true that $x\in A$
is not a limitpoint of $A$. For this you do not need the condition
that $A^{c}$ is dense as well.